# Relating two equations in a jump-diffusion process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to understand an argument involving the pricing kernel $\xi_t$ in the context of a simple jump diffusion model for the price of an asset $S_t$:
\begin{align}
   \xi_t = \exp \left[ -\theta W_t - \left( \frac{\theta^2}{2} + \lambda \kappa' \right)t + \sum_{n=1}^{N_t} (\gamma J_n + \nu) \right] \\
   \frac{dS_t}{S_{t^-}} = (\mu -\lambda \kappa) dt + \sigma dW_t + (e^J - 1) dN_t
\end{align}
where $W_t, N_t, J$ are mutually independent and $N_t$ follows a Poisson process such that $E^P((e^J - 1)dN_t) = E^P(e^J - 1) E^P(dN_t) = \kappa \lambda dt$. We also have $\kappa' = e^\nu E^P(\exp(\gamma J)) - 1$.

In that model, under the risk-neutral measure $Q$, we should find among other things these new parameter values for the jump part: $\kappa^* = E^Q(e^{J^*} - 1) \text{ and } \lambda^* = \lambda( \kappa' + 1)$. Now, I am not too familiar with jump-diffusion models, but to exploit my definition of $\kappa'$ later on, I would need to find something like this:
\begin{equation}
   \frac{d\xi_t}{\xi_{t^-}} = - \theta dW_t - \left( \frac{1}{2}\theta^2 + \lambda \kappa' \right)dt + \exp(\gamma J + \nu)dN_t
\end{equation}
because I plan on exploiting the Euler equation under $P$:
\begin{equation}
   E^P \left( \frac{d(\xi_t A_t)}{\xi_{t^-} A_{t^-}} \right) = 0
\end{equation}
where $A_t$ is the price of some asset. Here, I'll be using a riskless bond to find a relationship with the riskless rate of return and, obviously, the stock price whose dynamics under $P$ is given above. In principle, this gives me the mapping between the parameters of $\xi_t$ and those of the model for $S_t$ (and the riskless rate of return).

**Is it correct and, if so, can someone explicit the steps required to go from the pricing kernel to the differential equation describing its dynamics?** I suppose I could show that the level process solves the SDE, but I want to know how to move from the level process to the SDE.

I am able to do it, unfortunately, only if $\gamma, \nu = 0$.